# Are we graduating sometime soon?

Tags: discussion

Just a question about how we are doing - statistically, on Area 51, it doesn't look too bad.

I understand that many members are busy people (in real life), I know I am (5 jobs, 12 research projects etc). But *despite* this, there is still a steady stream of questions and answers.

My question is how close are we to graduating?  and what is needed to help us get to that point?

Comment: We've had this question come up on Space Exploration and Astronomy a couple of times. Basically, the deal is that Stack Exchange policy has changed a little bit so that Beta isn't exactly considered a temporary state anymore. Some sites could stay in Beta forever (without being at risk of being closed) if they are more minimal. However, I do believe Space Exploration and Astronomy are on the path to graduation, but it is not a process that there is any desire to rush. The community team will continue to let us grow until we are truly stable.

Comment: @called2voyage Does a clear growing tendency exist in the long-term stats?

Comment: @peterh Yes, a clear growing tendency exists from the start of the site.

Comment: @called2voyage Thanks! Then all is fine, it is only matter of time.

Comment: @peterh Not to be cynical, but the growth rate does not monotonically increase. Rather, Astro SE cycles between high activity and low activity. Using [this tool](http://codemanteau.com/stacker/?siteId=261), we see that the questions per day hasn't improved much over the last three years, but the visits per day has steadily grown. I think it's too early to tell whether the questions per day is increasing overall, but I'm still hopeful that the site will eventually graduate.

Comment: Not monotonic? Do people actually quit the stack? Why? I'd expect growth rate to speed up and slow down, but not see actual membership decreases.