# 999 questions with no answers and counting (downwards)

Tags: discussion, answers, statistics

Recently I started focusing on older unanswered questions, and I realized that today we reached 999 questions with no answers and I find this [repdigit number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit) (German: *Schnapszahl*) worth mentioning or celebrating.

Anyhow, my main question is: With no access to site statistics can I somehow determine the [answer ratio on Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy) of 1.6 myself?

[image]

I have the overall number of question (10566), the ones with no upvoted or accepted answers (1077), and the one with no answer at all (999). This looks like an underdetermined equation, so I would love to see a histogram of how many questions have 0, 1, 2, 3, ... answers. Just out of curiosity and since I love statistics.

#### Related

- [Are we graduating sometime soon?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/are-we-graduating-sometime-soon)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I would love to see a histogram of how many questions have 0, 1, 2, 3, ... answers

A while ago I wrote a query for this for [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/301356/70594), to demonstrate that it seems to follow Zipf's Law. When I run it for Astronomy, I get [the following graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/query/856666/questions-counted-by-number-of-answers#graph):

[image]
(both axes are logarithmic)

If you want raw results, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/query/1384669/questions-counted-by-number-of-answers-full) is better:

| Number of answers | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1342 |
| 1 | 5483 |
| 2 | 2480 |
| 3 | 790 |
| 4 | 270 |
| 5 | 95 |
| 6 | 42 |
| 7 | 13 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |

and here is your histogram, or at least the best I can do with SEDE:

[image]

As for where the 1.6 comes from: community members have guessed the formula and user @rene wrote a SEDE query [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300678/295232) and [running it for Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/query/720645) gives a value of 1.558, which is rounded to one decimal.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was hoping for power law (with a cutoff), but I am somehow excited that it is indeed one.